# Drawing a perpendicular line between a point along a line and a curve in R

Tags: r, math, geometry, curve

I am hoping to calculate the distance between the midpoint of one line and a curve above it in R, but am mathematically dense. My curves all look something like what is shown in the code below:

```
Curve <- data.frame(X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.9046, 6.1424, 7.275, 8.5851, 10.0373, 11.9981, 13.7726, 15.0731,16.0664, 
18.1945, 21.2666, 24.2093, 26.7119, 28.8037, 30.7135, 32.1351,  33.1982, 34.2341, 35.7587, 37.2147, 38.4303, 39.625, 40.4596, 42.0938, 42.7428, 42.7593, 43.5085, 43.7419, 43.5989, 44.0841, NA, NA, NA), 
Y = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -9.9938, -7.4596, -4.8647, -2.2903, 0.3158, 2.9302, 5.7262, 8.7033, 11.8007, 14.9847, 16.7225, 16.7813, 15.6921, 14.2964, 11.5579, 8.2378, 5.183, 1.5938, -2.0712, -5.195, -7.1447, -9.0446, -11.1269, -13.0979, -15.3295, -17.1898, -19.4376, -21.4781,-23.8426, -25.6343, NA, NA, NA),              
fan_line = 1:42)
```

I am able to draw a line between the first and last xy coordinates and find the midpoint of that line (as in the image below). From this midpoint I now need to construct a perpendicular line that extends from the midpoint up to the curve and extract the xy coordinates at this point. I'm at a loss as to how this is done.

[image]

All my plotting is done in ggplot if that is relevant, but principally I am interested in extracting the XY coordinates perpendicular to the midpoint shown in the image (the midpoint between the curve's first and last xy coordinates), so the values rather than the plotting itself.

I'd previously been calculating the mid x and y coordinates of the curve on the basis of the middle X-coordinate (ignoring NA values) but that's really not what I want at all.

Ultimately I am interested in obtaining a value that is the distance of the dotted line in my image, divided by the length of the perpendicular line.

Please excuse my mathematical ignorance

Edit: As Limey points out there are any number of perpendicular lines from a point. I mean vertical from the midpoint along the dotted line I've drawn.

Edit2: Sorry to be so unclear about what I'm looking for. Basically, I want to end up essentially obtaining something like the red line in the image below (forgive the Microsoft Paint job).

[image]

Comment: There are an infinite number of lines from your midpoint to the curve that arev perpendicular to the curve at the point of intersection with the curve.  Do you mean you want a *vertical* line from the point to the curve?  If not, you'll have to tell us how to indentify the point where your line intersects the curve...

Comment: Sorry, yes. I'm taking the wording from the paper I am trying to use the method from. (The lack of clarity was mine, not the paper's)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `approx()` function allows you to find the y coordinate corresponding to a given x coordinate, for example with:

```
approx(Curve$X, Curve$Y, mean(range(Curve$X, na.rm=TRUE)) )
# $x
# [1] 24.49435
# 
# $y
# [1] 16.65724
```

However it appears that you want to find the point on the curve which is perpendicular to the line between the endpoints at its midpoint. To do this, you can rotate the curve by the gradient of the line joining the endpoints so that the line is flat, use the approach above, and then rotate in the opposite direction. The code to do this is:

```
library(lava)

Ends <- Curve[Curve$X %in% range(Curve$X, na.rm=TRUE),]

theta <- atan(diff(Ends$Y)/diff(Ends$X))

rotCurve <- rotate2(as.matrix(Curve)[,1:2], theta)
rotEnds <- rotate2(as.matrix(Ends)[,1:2], theta)

rotPoint <- approx(rotCurve[,1], rotCurve[,2], mean(rotEnds[,1]) )

Point <- rotate2(matrix(c(rotPoint$x, rotPoint$y), ncol=2), -theta)
#         [,1]     [,2]
# [1,] 33.39819 4.490086
```

With a quick plot to verify it looks like your diagram

```
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=X, y=Y), Curve) + geom_line(aes(x=X, y=Y), data=Ends, lty=2) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=c(mean(Ends$X), Point[1]), y=c(mean(Ends$Y),Point[2])), colour='red') + coord_equal()
```

[image: Output plot]

Comment: That is very close to what I'm looking for, as it gives me the vertical line from the midpoint. However, I need a vertical line that takes into account the slope of the dotted line, so I was unclear about that, sorry. I'm going to post another edit though because I'm not being clear at all. I really appreciate the response though!

Comment: @SLewis Hopefully this is now what you're after

Comment: Thank you for this. It looks like exactly what I am looking for. I have one more question. I am starting out by looking at 'the point on the curve which is perpendicular to the line between the endpoints at its midpoint', but there are actually other points I want to look at too - one third of the way along the line and two thirds of the way. Is there a way to do this with the approx function too?

I'll try this all out tomorrow and see if it works for me and I'll mark your solution as solved if it works. Thanks!

Comment: You can change `mean(range(Curve$X, na.rm=TRUE))` to a different proportion of the way along either by calculation or by using a weighting to the mean

Comment: Hi Miff. I've posted another question relating to this I was helping you might be able to help with, [asking how to embed this within a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67059159/loop-through-files-obtain-theta-and-rotate-curve-by-theta-in-r)