# Loop through files, obtain theta and rotate curve by theta in R

Tags: r, math, dplyr, geometry

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66966660/drawing-a-perpendicular-line-between-a-point-along-a-line-and-a-curve-in-r) where Miff helped me figure out how to find the point on a curve which is perpendicular to the line between the endpoints at its midpoint.

To do this, the user pointed out it was necessary to rotate the curve by the gradient of the line joining the endpoints so that the line is flat, using `approx`, and then rotate in the opposite direction using the `lava` package. I can make this work on a case by case basis, establishing theta and working from there. I'm having really bad luck trying to embed this within a function, however.

I am having difficulty using dplyr to rotate each set of 42 points by a theta value within a function.

Here's a sample set of data. The real data has hundreds of curves I need to work through.

```
data <- structure(list(X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.9046, 
6.1424, 7.275, 8.5851, 10.0373, 11.9981, 13.7726, 15.0731, 16.0664, 
18.1945, 21.2666, 24.2093, 26.7119, 28.8037, 30.7135, 32.1351, 
33.1982, 34.2341, 35.7587, 37.2147, 38.4303, 39.625, 40.4596, 
42.0938, 42.7428, 42.7593, 43.5085, 43.7419, 43.5989, 44.0841, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -14.845, -11.9052, 
-8.7897, -5.8034, -2.6756, 0.3316, 3.4003, 6.5281, 9.6517, 12.804, 
15.9861, 19.1769, 22.2929, 25.4089, 28.3392, 31.0054, 33.1847, 
35.081, 36.7227, 38.1544, 39.1697, 40.049, 40.9647, 41.5014, 
41.8874, 42.1778, 42.3435, 42.2681, 42.3745, 42.4619, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Y = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -9.9938, -7.4596, 
-4.8647, -2.2903, 0.3158, 2.9302, 5.7262, 8.7033, 11.8007, 14.9847, 
16.7225, 16.7813, 15.6921, 14.2964, 11.5579, 8.2378, 5.183, 1.5938, 
-2.0712, -5.195, -7.1447, -9.0446, -11.1269, -13.0979, -15.3295, 
-17.1898, -19.4376, -21.4781, -23.8426, -25.6343, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8.0113, 9.1826, 9.838, 10.7908, 
11.175, 12.0393, 12.6813, 12.8828, 13.2281, 13.5102, 13.6637, 
13.5493, 12.8699, 12.2191, 10.9208, 9.0209, 6.2158, 3.2466, 0.2169, 
-2.7807, -6.0439, -9.1262, -11.8684, -14.7779, -17.5825, -20.2452, 
-22.807, -25.3519, -27.6105, -29.7536, NA, NA, NA, NA), fan_line = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
40L, 41L, 42L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -84L
))
```

Currently within the function, I loop through each set of 42 XY coordinates that constitute my curves of interest, and obtain the start and end XY coordinates for each curve:

`plyr`, `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `lava` are loaded

```
data <- data %>% mutate(Group = rep(1:(n()/42), each = 42)) %>% dplyr::group_by(Group) %>% 
    mutate(start = min(which(!is.na(X))), end = max(which(!is.na(X))), midpoint = round((start+end)/2, digits = 0)) %>% ungroup()

for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
    if (data[i, "fan_line"] == data[i, "start"]){
      data[i, "start_val_x"] = data[i, "X"]
      data[i, "start_val_y"] = data[i, "Y"]
    }
    else{data[i, "start_val_y"] = NA
    data[i, "start_val_x"] = NA}
  }
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
    if (data[i, "fan_line"] == data[i, "end"]){
      data[i, "end_val_x"] = data[i, "X"]
      data[i, "end_val_y"] = data[i, "Y"]
    }
    else{data[i, "end_val_y"] = NA
    data[i, "end_val_x"] = NA}
  }

data <- data %>%  group_by(Group) %>% fill(c(start_val_x, start_val_y), .direction = "down") %>% fill(c(start_val_x, start_val_y), .direction = "up")
data2 <- data %>%  group_by(Group) %>% fill(c(end_val_x, end_val_y), .direction = "down") %>% fill(c(end_val_x, end_val_y), .direction = "up")
```

Here I find points along a line running between the start and endpoints along each curve. In this cases, it is the one third point.

```
data3 <- data2 %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(x_value_one_third_hypo = ((start_val_x/3)*2 + (end_val_x*0.33)),
                                            y_value_one_third_hypo = ((start_val_y/3)*2 + (end_val_y*0.33)),
                                            third_x = approx(X, Y, (min(X, na.rm = T)/3)*2 + (max(X, na.rm = T)/3))$x,
                                            third_y = approx(X, Y, (min(X, na.rm = T)/3)*2 + (max(X, na.rm = T)/3))$y)
```

I calculate theta for each curve like so:

```
data3 <- data3 %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(theta = max(atan(diff(c(start_val_y, end_val_y))/diff(c(start_val_x, end_val_x))), na.rm = T))
```

However, I then run into the problem of trying to rotate using this theta value - I get an error message informing me that object theta is not found.

```
  data3.5 <- data3 %>% bind_cols(as_tibble(rotate2(as.matrix(.)[,1:2], theta = theta)))
```

I'm not sure how I can rotate the coordinates of each set of xy coordinates by their corresponding theta values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's an easier way to do this, but it works. That's assuming that you're trying to rotate about the origin. If you wanted to use an arbitrary axis, this won't be right.

I did have to change the data to work through this because there is no 80 to match to `end`, so I changed it to 38 just to work through the code.

I thought that the `lava` function required a square matrix, but that didn't work, so I went back to the more traditional rotation matrix.

[image: \sqrt{foo}]

Using the theta you calculated, I created this matrix in R

```
# create the 2D rotation matrix
tMat = rbind(c(cos(unique(data3$theta)), 
               -1* sin(unique(data3$theta))),
             c(sin(unique(data3$theta)), 
               cos(unique(data3$theta))))

# an empty list to store the results
trXY <- vector("list")   # transformed xy storage

# transform points - extract x & y, put into a vector, then matrix mult
for(i in 1:nrow(data3)){
  # collect original x and y
  coordData = data3[i, 1:2] %>% unlist()
 
  # skip the NA rows
  if(is.na(data3[i, 1]) == F) {
     # calculate
     results <- tMat %*% coordData
     # store the results
     trXY[i] <- list(results)
   } # end if
   else{
     # is NA
     trXY[i] <- NA
   } # end else
 } # end for

 # check output
 trXY[38] # it's stored in rows x is row 1; y is row 2

 # extract coordinates from the list and put them in the data frame
 # x coord
 data3$trX <- apply(trXY, function(x) ifelse(length(x) == 1,
                                             NA,
                                             x[[1]])) %>% unlist()
 # y coord
 data3$trY <- apply(trXY, function(x) ifelse(length(x) == 1,
                                             NA,
                                             x[[2]])) %>% unlist()

  # check rotation
  (p <- plotly::plot_ly(data3, 
                        x = ~X, 
                        y = ~Y, 
                        name = "original data", 
                        type = "scatter", 
                        mode = "lines", 
                        color = ~Group %>% as.factor(), 
                        colors = c("#cd0c18","#1660a7")) %>% 
     plotly::add_trace(x = ~trX, 
                       y = ~trY, 
                       name = "transformed", 
                       mode = "lines", 
                       color = ~Group %>% as.factor(), 
                       line = list(dash = "dash")))
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm afraid this didn't end up working for me in the end. There were a couple of typos (I think). E.g. `for(i in 1:nrow(data3)` rather than `for(i in 1:nrow(data3))` and `txXY` instead of `trXY`. Ultimately it just didn't seem to work within the function I'd created, so I went down a `dplyr` route. Really appreciate your help though!

Comment: I'm glad to hear you found a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the last line:
`data3.5 <- data3 %>% bind_cols(as_tibble(rotate2(as.matrix(.)[,1:2], theta = theta)))` which led to an error, I looked at the data using `group_modify` to perform the rotations and create a grouped tibble.

```
test <- data3.5 %>%
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  group_modify(~ as_tibble(rotate2(as.matrix(.x)[,1:2], theta = min(.x$theta))))
```

I then added the information from the grouped tibble to the old table using `bind_cols` after removing `Group` from the tibble (to avoid dupicate names).

```
  test$Group <- NULL 
  data3.5 <- bind_cols(data3.5, test)
```

Credit goes to TimTeaFan [who provided an answer to another related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67081565/use-a-pre-existing-value-within-a-function-in-dplyr)